# How best to include HTML with Gatsy site behind PrivateRoute?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I want to put HTML code that has been generated by Javadoc within a Gatsby site, such that the HTML is accessible only via an authenticated route.

Thus my site might look something like this, using [reach/router](https://reach.tech/router) for routing:

```
    <Layout>
        <Router>
            <PrivateRoute path={'/docs/api1'} component={MyApiDisplay}/>
            <PrivateRoute path={'/docs/api2'} component={MyApiDisplay}/>
            <NotFoundComponent default/>
        </Router>
    </Layout>
```

where `MyApiDisplay` is some component which would display the Javadoc, perhaps in an IFrame.

What is the best way of including the HTML into the Gatsby site?  The [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/) suggest using the `static` folder to hold the HTML, but that is public, which I don't want.

Comment: You could query the html files like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54444755/5385381

Answer (score 2):

1. Place your HTML in a content folder:

```
root
 |--content
 |   `--javadoc
 |       `--generated.html
```

2. Point gatsby-source-filesystem to your html folder:

```
// gatsby-config.js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/content/javadoc`,
    name: `javadoc`,
  },
},
```

3. In `gatsby-node.js`, you can use loadNodeContent to read the raw html. Follow the [API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#createNode) about creating nodes.

```
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node, loadNodeContent, actions
}) => {

  // only care about html file
  if (node.internal.type !== 'File' || node.internal.mediaType !== 'text/html') return;

  const { createNode } = actions;

  // read the raw html content
  const nodeContent = await loadNodeContent(node);

  // set up the new node
  const htmlNodeContent = {
    content: nodeContent,
    name: node.name, // take the file's name as identifier
    internal: {
      type: 'HTMLContent',
    }
    ...otherNecessaryMetaDataProps
  }

  createNode(htmlNode);
}
```

4. Create your [template component](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/) that queries and contains your HTML:

```
src/templates/blog-post.js

import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
export default ({ data }) => {
  const generated = allHtmlContent // Make sure to deconstruct your query result correctly
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>

        {*/ #### Supply your HTML markup to this template here #### /*}

        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: generated }} />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}


/* #### Query your HTML here #### */

export const query = graphql`
{
  allHtmlContent {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

5. Place your template component in a private route like you showed in your question.

Credit goes to @ksav and the [question he linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437048/how-can-i-create-blog-entries-for-gatsby-with-migrated-html-content/54444755#54444755).

---

## EDIT

> The output from Javadoc is not just HTML, it includes css, js and images. How does your answer change if these other file types need to be supported?

### css

Make sure you import your styles correctly `import "styles.css";` and the class names are set to what you need both in html and css.

### javascript

This [blog](https://uxworks.online/how-to-add-a-script-in-head-or-body-tag-in-your-gatsby-website/) gives several possibilities. The answer here depends on your implementation. I recommend a new question for that.

### images

Depends on whether you have absolute or relative paths. Absolute paths require no change. Relative paths might be a problem since Gatsby moves your files around. For relative paths I recommend a new question.

Comment: The output from Javadoc is not just HTML, it includes css, js and images.  How does your answer change if these other file types need to be supported?

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work for links within HTML pages.  It's a partial answer and  simply renders correctly a single HTML page tat stands on its own. I'm sorry, but I can't accept this answer as currently worded as the question refers to rendering a website (the output of Javadoc, which includes multiple file types and links between pages).